# Nested Json object is not formatted in java

Tags: java, json, format

I have the below Json which has inner object not formatted.

```
{
   "test1": "12334",
   "name": "my name",
   "load": "{\r\n\t\"Info\": {\r\n\t\t\"Method\": \"01\",\r\n\t\t\"Timestamp\": \"201612310246\",\r\n\t\t\"Data\": \"Data\"\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n"
}
```

Have tried the below , but still no luck.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
return objectMapper.readValue(row.value().toString(), Object.class);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you should have a custom class to parse the json into ? 
With either @JsonProperty annotation, or same field name that in json.

Comment: @J.Mengelle Thanks for your reply.. We don't want to use the custom class and wanted to keep it simple as the actual object is too huge and might impact performance.